# StepMonitor not working inside ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, bugs, version-9

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

Here is a toy example:

```
currentTimeStep = 0;
Dynamic[currentTimeStep]
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[
          {y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10000}, {a},
          StepMonitor :> (currentTimeStep = t;), MaxSteps -> 100000
       ];
pfun[1]
```

As you can see from the value of `currentTimeStep`, the variable is most of the time left without a numerical value. Is there a way to look at the current status of computation when using `ParameticNDSolveValue`?

Comment: I filed this as a bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ruebenko confirmed that this is a bug.

---

Here's a workaround:

```
currentTimeStep = 0;

monitor[t_?NumericQ] := (currentTimeStep = t; 1)

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a monitor[t] y[t], y[0] == 1},
    y, {t, 0, 10000}, {a}, MaxSteps -> 100000];

Dynamic[currentTimeStep]

pfun[1]
```